Smaller scopes within "matrix of nodes"
I'm using matrix of nodes to space out a generation in a family tree.

\documentclass[border=5pt,usenames,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,calc,fit,math}

%%%%%%%%%%%% Types of people
\tikzstyle{person} = [draw, text centered, text width=5.25em, minimum height=2em, anchor=mid]
\tikzstyle{consanguine} = [person, fill=LimeGreen!50]
\tikzstyle{affinal}     = [person, fill=brown!50]
%%%%%%%%%%%% Types of relationship
\tikzstyle{child} = [draw, ultra thick]
\tikzstyle{marry}   = [draw, thick, dotted]
\tikzstyle{divorce} = [draw, thick, loosely dotted]

\tikzset{
    sib matrix/.style n args={1}{%
        matrix of nodes,
        column sep=1cm,
        nodes={
            consanguine,
            execute at end node={\\ #1}
        },
    }
}

%%%%%%%%%%%% Connecting line commands
\newcommand{\marry}[3][marry]{
    \draw[#1] (#2.east) -- node(#2#3)[coordinate, midway]{} (#3.west);
}

\newcommand{\sibset}[3]{
    \foreach \n [count = \i from 0] in {#3}{
        \draw[child] (\n.north) |- ($(\n.north) + (0, 0.5)$);
        \coordinate (last) at ($(\n.north) + (0, 0.5)$);
        \ifnum\i<1
            \coordinate (first) at (last);
        \fi
    }
    \draw[child] (first) -- (last);% horizontal sib line
    \draw[child] (#1#2) -- (#1#2 |- first);% vertical parent line
}

%%%%%%%%%%%% Doc and pic begin here
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% gen 1
    \node[consanguine] (alberto)  at (0,0) {Alberto\\Aguilar\\Benítez};
    \node[consanguine] (beatriz) at (3,0) {Beatriz\\Calderón\\Díaz};
    
    \marry{alberto}{beatriz};

% gen 2
    \matrix (g1) [sib matrix={Aguilar Calderón}] at (1.5, -3) {
        |(geraldo)[affinal]| & |(catalina)| Catalina
        & |(dario)| Darío & |(hortensia)[affinal]|
        & |(elena)| Elena
        & |(fabian)| Fabián & |(ines)[affinal]|\\
    };
    \sibset{alberto}{beatriz}{catalina, dario, elena, fabian};
    
    \node[affinal] (geraldo) at (geraldo.mid) {Geraldo\\Espinosa\\Fernández};
    \node[affinal] (hortensia) at (hortensia.mid) {Hortensia\\García\\Herrera};
    \node[affinal] (ines) at (ines.mid) {Inés\\Ibáñez\\Jiménez};
    \marry[divorce]{geraldo}{catalina};
    \marry{dario}{hortensia};
    \marry{fabian}{ines};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Question 1
Within a single matrix, I want to have 2 styles of cells: consanguine and affinal:

consanguine as the default, which automatically affixes the surname
affinal as an alternative, which overrides consanguine

Right now, after the matrix I have this:

I then have to manually add new cells for the in-laws which cover up the cells the matrix creates. execute at end node appears to be a really hard thing to override. I can set it so affinal affixes something else on the end in addition to the surname, but not instead of.
Is there perhaps any way to have exclusive classes in LaTeX, the way you can in CSS with the :not() selector? Apply execute at end node to every node inside the matrix that's not of the class affinal?
Question 2
Is it possible to build \sibset into the matrix? Or even just part of it — for example, drawing a short vertical line from the top of each consanguine node?

The node contents key allows setting the whole text of a node via PGFKeys but this is not really applicable in a matrix of nodes. I'd propose a different syntax. If you only have one row of nodes in a matrix, you can do just all in one cell with a nice \foreach loop. Are you aware of packages like genealogytree?

@Qrrbrbirlbel I'm using a minimal reproducible example here. My actual application does not have only one row.

Please confine your question to one problem (== question) only. Though it's tolerable here, putting more focus helps everyone. Thank you
